# Trying to get a single row of data - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem about writing a SQL query on trying to get interviews conducted by a single staff

I have tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    instructor_id,
    progess_made,
FROM
    bookings, staff

    WHERE progess_made LIKE "New";
```

but the output I am getting is this :

```
# instructor_id, progess_made, 
'1007', 'New', 
'1008', 'New', 
'1014', 'New',
```

I want output like this, only want to select one staff

```
# instructor_id, progess_made,
'1007', 'New',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a LIMIT 1 will do the job nicely but then which row you get is pretty much indeterminate. Better to add the instructor id to the where clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    instructor_id,
    progess_made,
FROM
    bookings, staff /** <-- this sort of implicit join should be avoided */

    WHERE progess_made LIKE "New" AND instructor_id =1007
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I think that is the root of your problem.  Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT instructor_id, progess_made,
FROM bookings b JOIN
     staff s
     ON b.staffid = s.staffid  -- I made up these columns
WHERE progess_made LIKE 'New';
```

I made up the columns for the `JOIN`.  Use the appropriate columns for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the **LIMIT** at the end I added.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    instructor_id,
    progess_made,
FROM
    bookings, staff

    WHERE progess_made LIKE "New"
LIMIT 1;
```

You can limit n# or records using the LIMIT clause. You can also use this for paging purposes. 
Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Say I want to select instructor_id 1014 instead only?

Comment: add in the WHERE clause `AND instructor_id=1014`

Comment: see what @Gordon Linoff says : "Simple rule: Never use commas in the FROM clause. Always use proper, explicit JOIN syntax." i Vote down

Comment: @BerndBuffen I copied the OP query. This has nothing to do with his question.